# WPF Tree in ComboEditor - Infragistics WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, datacontext

I'm currently working on a WPF .NET 4.7 application and I use Infragistics WPF controls version 18.

I need to create a custom `XamComboEditor` which has a `XamDataTree` inside. Thus a ComboBox with a Tree selection inside.

The Tree selection works fine without the XamComboEditor and looks like this:

```
<iWPF:XamDataTree ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <iWPF:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
        <iWPF:NodeLayout Key="Locations" TargetTypeName="LocationViewModel" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <iWPF:NodeLayout Key="ChildLocations" TargetTypeName="string"/>
    </iWPF:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
</iWPF:XamDataTree>
```

[image]

My XamDataTree is bound to an observable collection `Locations`:

```
public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> Locations { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>();

public class LocationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<LocationViewModel> ChildLocations { get; set; } = new List<LocationViewModel>();
}
```

I need to use the style setter on my `XamComboEditor` to put the `XamDataTree` inside the combobox.

My problem is now, I don't know how to achieve this, or how to pass the context from the `XamComboEditor` further to the `XamDataTree`.

I tried the following, in vain:

```
<iWPF:XamComboEditor ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <iWPF:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <iXaml:XamDataTree ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                            <iXaml:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
                                <iXaml:NodeLayout Key="Locations" TargetTypeName="LocationViewModel" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <iXaml:NodeLayout Key="ChildLocations" TargetTypeName="string"/>
                            </iXaml:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
                        </iXaml:XamDataTree>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </iWPF:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
</iWPF:XamComboEditor>
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? Do you know how to pass the data context from the parent control to, let's say, the child control? Or rather, how to put the `XamDataTree` inside the `XamComboEditor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, the `DataContext` of your `XamlDataTree` is no what you expect it to be (the `Locations` bound in you `XamComboEditor`).

One way to solve this problem is to specify the source of the path in your `Binding` markup extension.
You can use the `{x:Reference ...}` markup extension to reference a named controled in your control tree.

```xml
<iWPF:XamComboEditor x:Name="comboEditor" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <iWPF:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <iXaml:XamDataTree ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=comboEditor}, Path=DataContext.Locations}">
                            <iXaml:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
                                <iXaml:NodeLayout Key="Locations" TargetTypeName="LocationViewModel" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <iXaml:NodeLayout Key="ChildLocations" TargetTypeName="string"/>
                            </iXaml:XamDataTree.GlobalNodeLayouts>
                        </iXaml:XamDataTree>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </iWPF:XamComboEditor.ComboBoxStyle>
</iWPF:XamComboEditor>
```

You can also achieve this without naming your controls with the `RelativeSource` property in the Binding (something like `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=iWPF:XamComboEditor}`).

Comment: thanks, this works like a charm - it brought me a full step further! have a nice day!

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboEditor, Path=DataContext.Locations}